# Can I prevent chart values disappearing on the edges of x-axis of Highcharts after zooming?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, highcharts, zooming

I'm using highcharts-react-official for a histogram with typescript. The problem I'm facing is, when user zooms in the values on the extreme of x-axis disappear (highlighted relevant x-axis values).
[highchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTOZ.png)

The zoom configurations that I'm using in Highcharts are something like this:
[zoom on x-axis only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJv5e.png)

I did go through Highcharts documentation and some articles as well, but couldn't find any solution. If you have any previous experience in Highcharts then I'm sure you would be able to assist me here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `cropThreshold` property. From Highcharts API:

> **cropThreshold: number**
>
> When the series contains less points than the crop threshold, all
> points are drawn, event if the points fall outside the visible plot
> area at the current zoom. The advantage of drawing all points
> (including markers and columns), is that animation is performed on
> updates. On the other hand, when the series contains more points than
> the crop threshold, the series data is cropped to only contain points
> that fall within the plot area. The advantage of cropping away
> invisible points is to increase performance on large series.
>
> *Defaults to 50.*

You can increase the value:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cropThreshold: 9e9
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w6y4zdk8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.cropThreshold